# Explanation of a racc code

Tags: ruby, yacc

I started to use Ruby language and I learn at this time about creating my own toy language using Ruby & Racc,
I need an explanation of this racc code please:

1) what does mean left & right in Yacc ?

> Left  '.'
>
> Right '='

Comment: a bit more context would help a lot. but they are probably the names of non-terminals.

Comment: Looks to me like the Yacc/Bison [precedence declaration] (http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Precedence-Decl.html#Precedence-Decl) `%left` and `%right`.  I found a note in passing that says Racc doesn't use the percent sign in its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [operator precedence and associativity specification](https://github.com/tenderlove/racc/blob/master/rdoc/en/grammar.en.rdoc).  From the doc:

> Here we can see how to designate operator precedence:

```
– prechigh

nonassoc '++'
left     '*' '/' 
left     '+' '-' 
right    '='

preclow –
```

> The token written in the line closer to prechigh has the higher
>   precedence. You can also write this in reverse order, such as defining
>   preclow before prechigh at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Best tutorial I've found for rex and racc was this one: http://testerstories.com/a-tester-learns-rex-and-racc-part-1/

Also, either rex or racc or both are written for ruby 1.8  Going from memory here, but I think one of them has `String#each`, just need to update it to `each_char` or `chars` if you want to use a more recent ruby version.